# Is there a way to SEO pages that dynamically change on EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an ember app that has a page that dynamically change the content.
Example url: `mydomain.com/shops/show/products/120`

The issue is SEO on this page didn't work (unable to crawl this page) and when I sent a link of this page to social networks, it doesn't display the correct meta tags I set.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about SEO and not related to code

Comment: this is actually *not* about SEO because google *does* execute JS when crawling. However other services dont. So have a look at [fastboot](https://ember-fastboot.com/) and [prember](https://github.com/ef4/prember)

Comment: Will fastboot and prember works on ? dynamically changing pages @Lux

Comment: Basically fastboot is for dynamically changing pages and premier (which uses fastboot) is for more static pages.

Comment: @Lux Currently my app is served on nginx web server. Will fastboot still work?

Comment: @chaelgutierrez No. Your content is changing dynamically. So you can not serve static files anymore. Instead you need to let Fastboot answer the requests (at least the ones, which aren't for static pages). Fastboot is a node application. You can use nginx as a proxy in front of Fastboot (which is a common setup) but you will need it additionally. See [Ember FastBoot App Server](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/fastboot-app-server#ember-fastboot-app-server) for additional information.